# mod_rewrite for flat links behaves like it's in the subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a `mod_rewrite` ruleset in `.htaccess` so that I can create some flat links to functionality in a page.

When the user enters: `http://example.com/where/location`

I want to redirect to : `http://example.com/index.php?where=location`

I'm currently using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^where/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?where=$1
```

which kind of works, except that css, JS and image links in `index.php` are no longer found - it's as though the server is serving index.php up from the non-existant `/where/location` sub-directory.

Is this what's happening and is there a way to case the server to serve index.php with relative links from its actual location in the root directory normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server side is irrelevant here. You *are* in fact serving the site from `/where/location`; it's irrelevant that this URL is getting rewritten internally. If you're using relative paths to CSS files, the *browser* is resolving those against the current URL that it is on. The best strategy is typically to use absolute paths for included files, e.g.:

```
/css/style.css
```

instead of

```
css/style.css
```

Comment: I guess that's good practice anyway - just need to check all my source code now.